# Why does DB2 error on long value for some users but not others?

Tags: java, db2, openjpa

I am using a DB2 9.7 select statement (through OpenJPA) which is working for me but not for my client. It is like:

```
SELECT COUNT(t) FROM MyTable t WHERE t.type = :type
```

`type` is `VARCHAR(4)` in DB2

When type is set to a String of length 5, the statement works find for me (returns 0 count), but gives a SQL Exception when my client runs it. What could be the difference here? I'd like to make sure it is failing for me as well so I can catch such issues in the future.

Comment: What is the exception that your client is getting?  What is the value that you are setting the :type parameter too?  Is it longer than 4 characters?  That might cause an exception to be thrown.  Also, are you and your client both using the exact same JDBC driver?

Comment: I don't have the exception details from my client. Yes, the :type value being set is longer than 4 characters, like 'Draft'. Yes, he is saying he is using the exact same JDBC driver as me.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too quickly, I see you said it was 5 characters.  Without having the exception it will be pretty hard to figure this one out.  Do you have the same data your client has?

Comment: Yes, we use the same data, but set up the DB on our own. Could it be some property when setting up the DB that could cause the difference in behavior? Or maybe there was a DB2 patch that changed this behavior.

Comment: I guess it's possible.  I don't have DB2 to play around with this.  Could you get the DDL for the table your client is using to compare to your own?  I keep thinking that the type parameter being longer than the column could be troublesome.  I assume when the client executes a query with a type that is 4 or fewer characters it executes ok?

Comment: The SQL statement used to create the table is the same for both of us.

Comment: The exception would really help us narrow in on the problem.

Comment: Did you make sure the same SQL was generated by OpenJPA for both of you ? You can enabled OpenJPA traces for verifying that. OpenJPA uses CASTS on parameters and that cause issues like that.